# Life steal or LOH better for Sweeping Wind/Cyclone build?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-monk

As the title says. I'm currently using a 2-hander build with Wave of Light, but having just sold a very nice amulet for 220m gold, I'm looking to convert to a dual-wield SW build like all the cool kids are using.

For reference, right now my weapon is a 1500 LOH, 5.4% LS 2h sword and I'm doing MP3 with no problems. It's rather slow though on account of having relatively little +crit damage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SW does not proc LOH, so using it will never add anything with a SW build, however, it wouldn't be taking away anything either. SW does proc LS but at 45% of weapon damage (with 3 stacks) and only 20% effectiveness in Inferno, you'd be needing to do much higher damage than what you'd be doing in MP3 for it to make a huge difference.

For example if your weapons do 2000 dps then 5% LOH should work out something like this

```
2000 * .45 * .2 * .05 = 5
```

Or 2000 weapon damage with 3 stacks of SW, and one enemy would work out to about 9 life regen. That's if the proc coefficient on SW is 1, if it's lower then so is the number (I coudln't find what the proc coefficient was). Also not sure how your offhand weapon figures into the weapon damage calculation. Of course this number should go up if you get swarmed but even with 10 enemies in your SW that's only 90 life regen, if they've trapped you on top of a ground effect, that probably won't save you.

Comment: that last sentence doesn't make much sense.  How do you higher damage than a monster difficulty?  And remember 3 full stacks of SW is actually 45% weapon damage, which isn't bad at all

Comment: You're right I expanded it a bit.

Comment: I thought the proc coefficient of SW is 0, which is why it doesn't proc anything.

Comment: Shouldn't that be 2000 * .45 * .05 * .2 = 9?  You forgot to take the 5% into account.  Of course 2000 is ridiculously low for DPS, but even at 200,000 DPS you're still only managing 900 life regen.  Life steal is not effect by proc coefficients.

Comment: Does SW do 45% of your overall dps or does it do 45% of your weapon DPS?

Comment: @nine9ths technically its 45% of your MH weapon damage, applied at a rate of your weapon attack speed and multiplied by the usual stat and crit multipliers.  Roughly, it works out to be about 45% of your dps, but if you have a super high main hand and a super weak off hand, it'll be higher than that.